# C# WinForm why form1.Text = "title" does not change my form's title?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I am making an application in C#, a windows form app with .NET Core 3.1 and when I change the property "Text" of my form, the title doesn't change, here is my code :

```
 //form
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.ico");
        this.Text = "Title";
  //form - end
```

Comment: Your question and title do not agree. also: where does this code sit??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short guess on this, did you put this before or after InitializeComponent ?
You should do property settings after calling InitializeComponent. This isnt obvious in your code snippet.

Comment: **Hint:** There is nothing/null **before** `InitializeComponent`.